# WordPress: Echo Javascript for Google Ads Conversion Page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to add some Javascript coming from Google for Ad Conversions on the thank you page. So this script should only appear on one page. Trying to use an if statement in PHP to echo the code but running into errors. This is what I currently have (with the Google ID replaced with something generic):

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'thankyou' )) {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-12345678901234567890123456'});'
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

The first and third echo's are fine but the middle one is not. What might be the proper fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your second echo line breaks your string.

You have 2 options to fix this:

**1. Change the inner quotes to double quotes**

```
echo 'gtag("event", "conversion", {"send_to": "AW-12345678901234567890123456"});';
```

**2. Break out of the quotes.**

You can use back slashes to not break out of your main string.

```
echo 'gtag(\'event\', \'conversion\', {\'send_to\': \'AW-12345678901234567890123456\'});';
```

I have also noticed on the second echo you were missing a semi colon.

Source: [PHP-Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for the answers. Unfortunately, all the ideas brought up the WSOD. Put WP  DEBUG on and got the following:

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/hellod8/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php on line 99

Comment: @AdamBell did you close your if statement. In your code snippet you are missing a }

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes in the brackets of `gtag()`.

Try `echo 'gtag(\'event\', \'conversion\', {\'send_to\': \'AW-12345678901234567890123456\'});'` instead.